# mysqldump restore error - Invalid default value for field type timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I am trying to restore a mysqldump of Magento 1.8 database (hosted on MySQL 5.6 Community) into MySQL 5.5 Community server and I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 190: Invalid default value for 'created_at'
```

Looking at my `.sql` file around this line, it appears to be this block of query:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `api2_acl_role`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `api2_acl_role`;
CREATE TABLE `api2_acl_role` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned auto_increment,
  `created_at` timestamp DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
  `updated_at` timestamp,
  `role_name` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_API2_ACL_ROLE_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
  KEY `IDX_API2_ACL_ROLE_UPDATED_AT` (`updated_at`)
)/*! engine=InnoDB comment='Api2 Global ACL Roles' */;
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any `'` around `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it's a special function in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks. I did a search and replace on the file and re-tried it and I am no longer getting that error. Now I am getting a different error: `ERROR 1170 (42000) at line 3268: BLOB/TEXT column 'data_index' used in key specification without a key length` - the line it's referring to is this block of SQL: http://pastebin.com/midG4dsP

Answer (score 0):

There is two issue I see with your `CREATE` statement as pointed below

Remove `'` (single quote) from `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` in below line. That's not a string literal.

```
`created_at` timestamp DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

*[Per your comment]*

The error happens because `MySQL` can index only the first N chars of a BLOB or TEXT column and you are not specifying any length for `data_index` column while defining the key as below.

```
KEY `FTI_CATALOGSEARCH_FULLTEXT_DATA_INDEX` (`data_index`)
```

Your `CREATE` statement should look like

```
CREATE TABLE `catalogsearch_fulltext` (
  `fulltext_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED,
  `store_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED,
  `data_index` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fulltext_id`),
  UNIQUE `UNQ_CATALOGSEARCH_FULLTEXT_PRODUCT_ID_STORE_ID` 
  (`product_id`,`store_id`),
  KEY `FTI_CATALOGSEARCH_FULLTEXT_DATA_INDEX` (`data_index`(255))) <-- Here
```

Check this [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d103) if in doubt.